# Demand `T extends Comparable<T>` only for certain methods

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a generic class in Java. A few methods in that class require that `T extends Comparable<T>`. How can I make it such that `T` is required to be comparable only if one of those methods is used? Or maybe there's some other way I should organize my class?

Here's the class I'm trying to implement. Its and array that I plan to use on both comparable and non-comparable types.

```
// I know Java has its own containers, but this
// is homework and I'm not allowed to use them
class Array<T>
{
    // Some methods that pose no
    // special restrictions on T

    // These require that T be comparable
    public Array<T> union(...) {...}
    public Array<T> intersect(...) {...}
}
```

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can show some snippets of what you want to do ?

Comment: union and intersect do not require Comparable, just equals().

Comment: @ignis They require comparable if the lists are assumed to be sorted and you want the result to be sorted as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide type `T` for method. `T` of `Test` is not the same as `T` of `CompareMethod`here.

```
public static class Test<T> {
    <T extends Comparable<T>> void compareMethod(T t, Class<T> classt) {
    }
    void normalMethod(T t) {
    }
}
```

Now example

```
    Test<String> test = new Test<String>();//Comparable class
    test.compareMethod("",String.class);//works fine
    Test<Random> tes1t = new Test<Random>();//Non Comparable class
    tes1t.compareMethod(new Random(),Random.class);//Compilation error here 
    tes1t.normalMethod(new Random());//Works fine
    new Test<Random>().compareMethod("",String.class);// Not a good but can be valid
new Test<String>().compareMethod(new Random(),Random.class);//Compilation error here
```

**Update:**

After being cursed about this solution I did some search in java API and this practice gets followed for `toArray()` method

```
ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();
string.toArray(new Integer[5]);<--Illegal however <T> is hide by toArray method
```

Comment: Won't this will just involve an unsafe cast though?

Comment: @Antimony  There isn't compiler prevents from it

Comment: Please clarify that the T of compareMethod is NOT the T of Test. So you could have new Test<String>().compareMethod(new Random()).

Comment: @AmitD: Using comparable and then using normalMethod as method name is just not useful. Comparable is used for sorting purposes and that also in Collections Sort. the methods need to overloaded and also the Sorting using comparison will be done for same type only. not between those which are non comparable.

Comment: @VineetVerma I think it is just the illustration of what OP wants to do which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: How does this answer the question at all? The OP wants to only be able to use the method if the type `T` of the class is comparable to itself. For example, `Array<T>` has a method called `public void sort()` that will only work if `T` is comparable to itself. This does not answer it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: It looks like this is possible after all (see AmitD's post). But anyway, other possible solutions are

1. Refactor the methods requiring comparable into a subclass
2. Just use casts in the relevant methods, meaning that that part will only be checked at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It wont be possible through normal method such as using comparable.

It would be better if you share what is the exact requirement.

If Sorting in ArrayList/Arrays are your goal, then Comparing Non Comparable classes is useless. Sorting can only be done in objects of the same or sub types.

But if you are going to use compare for checking if the objects are equal or not then I'll suggest that you override equals(Object O) method.